# gae can i migrate local mysql to cloudsql

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've written a GAE app using Python and Django and an MySQL database which is running on my pc.  I now want to load this onto app engine and use ClousSQL.  Setting up the databases on my pc was easy because I just run the

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

and

```
$ python manage.py migrate myapp
```

How do I get the database set up on CloudSQL?

Comment: hope you happy with that link..

Comment: Avinash Raj - I've followed the link and I'm trying to implement it and I'm clearly doing something wrong.  I cannot get my system to select the elif option which I'm trying to understand first.  Once I've sorted I'll close as appropriate

Comment: I've tried following these instructions but I simply get a "No changes detected" message when I run manage.py makemigrations and "No migrations to apply" when I run manage.py migrate.  I've tried this several ways, including changing settings.py to remove the if clause and only allow connection to the cloudsql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you set up the database locally, you can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) to make a copy of it and import it to your remote CloudSQL instance. For example:

Connect to your local instance:

```
$ mysql --host=localhost --user=user-name --password
```

Import your local database to your remote instance:

```
mysql> mysqldump --databases database-name --host instance-IP --user=user-name --password
```

For more details see Connecting to [Google Cloud SQL Using MySQL Client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client).

Comment: I could connect to the instance but not update the mysqldump result to the it. Instead, I've done it by hand, creating a file with the mysqldump result and copying + pasting it on my instance (which was connected to the Google Cloud database)

Comment: This is the approach I took in the end but I'm not happy with it because I wanted to set up the database structures from scratch.  Still, worked for now..